# Passing parameters between views in ViewStack

Tags: apache-flex

I'm wondering how I would pass a value to "SelectedChild" in ViewStack:

In the example below, I am trying to set a public property in a form called "register" after I have navigated there from another form called "login".

The result I get seems to be a compilation error:

```
Error: Access of possibly undefined property pagename through a reference 
with static type mx.core:INavigatorContent. 
vsMain.selectedChild.pagename = "register page";
```

Any idea what the solution would be?
Thank you.

```
 <mx:Panel x="0" y="0" width="285" height="221"
     layout="absolute" title="ViewStack Basic ">
    <mx:ViewStack x="0" y="0" id="vsMain" width="100%" height="100%">
          <mx:Canvas id="cnvLogin" label="Login" width="100%" height="100%">
            <mx:Script>
            public function myClick():void  { 
                vsMain.selectedChild=cnvRegister;
                vsMain.selectedChild.pagename = "register page";
            }
            </mx:Script>

        <mx:Label x="10" y="10" text="Login Page" fontWeight="bold"/>
        <mx:Label x="10" y="36" text="Username:"/>
        <mx:TextInput x="85" y="34" id="txtLoginUser"/>
        <mx:Label x="10" y="62" text="Password:"/>
        <mx:TextInput x="85" y="60" id="txtLoginPass"/>
        <mx:Button x="10" y="100" label="Login" id="butLogin"/>
        <mx:LinkButton x="126" y="100" label="Need to Register?" enabled="true"
           click="myClick()"/>
      </mx:Canvas>
      <mx:Canvas id="cnvRegister" label="Register" width="100%" height="100%">
          <mx:Script>
         [Bindable]
            public var pagename:String;

          </mx:Script>
        <mx:Label x="10" y="10" text="{name}" fontWeight="bold"/>
        <mx:Label x="10" y="36" text="uname"/>
        <mx:TextInput x="107" y="34" id="txtRegUser" width="138"/>
        <mx:Label x="10" y="62" text="Password:"/>
        <mx:TextInput x="107" y="60" id="txtRegPass" width="138"/>
        <mx:Label x="10" y="90" text="Password Again:"/>
        <mx:TextInput x="107" y="88" id="txtRegPassAgain" width="138"/>
        <mx:Button x="10" y="141" label="Register" id="butRegister"/>
        <mx:LinkButton x="107" y="141" label="Already Registered?" enabled="true"
           click="{vsMain.selectedChild=cnvLogin}"/>

      </mx:Canvas>
    </mx:ViewStack>
  </mx:Panel>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading it correctly, what you're trying to do is just pass data from one view in the viewstack to another view?  What you should do is have a bindable data model at on the same level as the viewstack:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        // Just a class with public variables where you save/bind data
        [Bindable] private var _model:SomeModel;  
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:ViewStack>
    <!-- You need to create a public variables 'dataProvider' in both there views -->
    <View1 dataProvider="{this._model}" />
    <View2 dataProvider="{this._model}" />
</mx:ViewStack>
```

If you change the data in the first view, the second view will be able to see it when it gets instantiated.

Comment: I have an error, trying to create dataProvider for Canvas objects:

 <mx:Canvas id="cnvLogin" label="Login" width="100%" height="100%" dataProvider="{this._model}">

 Error: Cannot resolve attribute 'dataProvider' for component type mx.containers.Canvas.
I am doing it incorrectly?

Comment: Yes.  Canvas does not have a dataProvider property, you need to create it by creating a custom component (create a new mxml file) which extends Canvas (or whatever UIComponent you want), in which you add the dataProvider getter/setter within it. You should read up on how to create extended components.

Answer (score 1):

You should move the declaration to the top element to make the variable public for the ViewStack components:

```
<mx:Script>
    [Bindable]
    public var pagename:String;
</mx:Script>

<mx:Panel x="0" y="0" width="285" height="221"
    layout="absolute" title="ViewStack Basic ">
    <mx:ViewStack x="0" y="0" id="vsMain" width="100%" height="100%">
    ...
```